# "Multiple statement error" in IDLE v34

Tags: python, statements

I am currently learning Python using Jason Briggs' book. I tried entering some code from the book into the IDLE shell and getting a "multiple statement error" message. I've even deleted and re-inserted 4 spaces in all the lines of code.

I have had this issue before, but couldn't find out how to solve it. I searched online, but I don't think I have an indentation or coding error.

I'm using IDLE 34 on Windows Professional 7. This is what I typed into the IDLE shell:

```
found_coins = 20
magic_coins = 70
stolen_coins = 3
coins = found_coins
for week in range(1, 53):
    coins = coins + magic_coins - stolen_coins
    print('Week %s = %s' % (week, coins))
**Click Enter**
```

The error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please help. Multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771573/please-help-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement)

Comment: Have you copied and pasted it? It should work if you properly type it clicking enter after every line

Comment: If you have typed that `**Click Enter**` too, it's no wonder you get a syntax error.

Comment: Haha. I didn't. I wanted to show all keyboard actions. Sorry. Is it better to post a screenshot?

Comment: Well,well. Another day, another attempt. This time it works fine. The reason I posted, it was not the first time. I will investigate this further and see if anything worth sharing comes up.Thks for your time and efforts. ArijJan